# GUI and backend choices for a C-code simulator

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio, qt, gtk

I have to make a simulator. Functionalities are mentioned below:

Inputs: Unchangeable C codes

Function: Compile and run those codes and produce outputs. Each C code may variables. Input function (time based) is given for all those variables. So, if the input c code file has a simple adder int add(a,b)/* a and b change with time with a specified fn. So, at t=0 a=1,b=2 at t=4 b may change to 6 and so on*/ I have to run the code at diff times and generate outputs. Check those o/ps too. For all those purposes, I would need a GUI too.

Need suggestions for both backend and Gui tool.

P.S: My research tells me C backend with GTK for GUI is a workable solution but GTK is too lengthy and tedious. I am confused about Qt/C++ as it may not work all that well with a c backend. C++ backend would be difficult for me to import and run those input codes (extern doesnt work all the time). I also looked at C# for GUI and the linkings to dll files but that is also mentioned in many blogs as not so feasible. Any suggestions? Thanks already.

P.P.S Please suggest open source and non-licensed tools only.

Comment: by unchangeable you mean that they're known at the time of designing your simulator?

Comment: At this your current time your question is very broad.  Any answer would only help you.  If you have a specific question you should ask it.  Please limit your scope.  Your question `as-is` does not explain the reason "workable" solutions cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

C++ can and does interface trivially with any C library or "code" out there, so that's not your concern.

I'd suggest using Qt. It comes with a nice, free IDE: Qt Creator. It offers high-level functionality that often surpasses GTK. Alas, GTK library ecosystem is very "hackable" -- the underlying object model allows all sorts of creative uses and abuses, but has IMHO a very shallow learning curve -- it'll take you much longer to "fully" understand GTK than Qt.

That's simply because GTK's underlying low-level libraries offer a lot of functionality that's taken over by the C++ language or simply hidden from view in Qt. I've found GTK's underpinnings to be more flexible, but it seems all a solution in search of a problem. Qt's/C++'s much simpler and less flexible object model works just as well and is easier to learn because there's much less of it.

Think also from the viewpoint of investing your time. Learning to be proficient in C++ is portable to other projects that merely use the same language. Learning to be proficient in glib only helps you with C projects that specifically use glib, and there's much less of them I'd think than C++ projects.

Sometimes too much of a good thing is a bad thing, and that seems -- to me -- to be the case with GTK. It's a library collection that's bottom heavy with low-level functionality, but seems to be light on higher-level abstractions. Never mind that the individual libraries are all designed with slightly different guiding principles and are essentially a loosely bound collection. That's good in theory for decoupling of the components, but makes learning much harder as there's really little in the way of common design elements in the various libraries that make up GTK.

Qt, in contrast, is pretty much a single, uniform large library split into modules that you can elect not to use.

PS. Most people use "steep learning curve" incorrectly to mean that something is hard to learn. A learning curve shows "knowledge" vs. time. If it's steep, that means you are learning fast. A shallow one means you're learning slowly.